# Loop over only the names that match the string instead of the entire array

Tags: intersystems-cache

There are two names stored in ^ZNAME and they are MITCHELL, DAVID J and SMITH, JOHN A.

```
N prompt,val
S prompt="Enter a name (LAST,FIRST MI): "
F  W !,prompt R val Q:val=""  D
.   I val'?1.A1",".1" "1.A.1(1" "1A) W !,"Invalid name"
.   E  S ^ZNAME(val)=""
F  S val=$O(^ZNAME(val)) Q:val=""  D
.   W !,"You entered: ",val
Q

^ZNAME("MITCHELL, DAVID J")
^ZNAME("SMITH, JOHN A")
```

I can enter "SM" and get the desired results of SMITH, JOHN A. But I want to improve this code to loop over only the names that match the string instead of the entire array. I have been at this for two days now. I have added $L and $E commands to this code, but failed at getting the desired result. I definitely want to know what I am doing wrong. Would someone be able to offer guidance on the steps to obtain this improvement. Thank you.

```
N partial,val
S partial="Enter a name or partial name: "
F  W !,partial R val Q:val=""  D
.   W !,$O(^ZNAME(val))
Q
```

I made some changes to the code to try and get the result but it keeps reading the ^ZNAME and not reading in the name.

```
N name,val,len,pos,char,
    S name="Enter a name or partial name: "
    I name=""  Q
    S len=$L(name)
    F pos=1:1:len  D
    .S char=$E(name,pos)
    S char=""
    F  S char=$O(^ZNAME(char)) Q:char=""  D
    .W !,char
    Q
```

Comment: It would be better if you will add how your `^ZNAME` originally looks

Comment: I made the change to the VAL and added how the ^ZNAME.

Comment: I made some changes to my code see above.

Answer (score 0):

Why `^ZNAME("val")` when it should be `^ZNAME(val)`

Comment: Apologies it is ^ZNAME(val). I inadvertently added the quotes when writing the code on this page.